# How to close all windows7 folders using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7

I am using python 2.7 and i work with a lot of open windows7 folders and with other programs at the same time. I have tried working with this code (in works fine perfect):

```
import os

os.system('taskkill /im chrome.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im powerpnt.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im outlook.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im winword.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im excel.exe')
```

but i don't know how to close all the folders and files (windows 7) at the same time too.
I have tried the following

[how to close remote desktop window using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854866/how-to-close-remote-desktop-window-using-python)

[How to Close a program using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625524/how-to-close-a-program-using-python)

[How to close all windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725629/how-to-close-all-windows)

but didn't understand the way to do it with python.
Also, i tried to search the name process in the Task Manager but i didn't know the name of it. 
[image]

Is it possible to do it without damaging the operating system of the computer?

Comment: The name of the process I think you're looking for is "Windows Explorer" or 'explorer.exe'. Typically all explorer windows run in one process, which is *the same process* that displays the desktop and taskbar. I'm not sure how you would go about killing all folder windows without also killing the desktop, but there may be a way.

Comment: yes i think also there is a way to do it -but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nircmd (You need install nircmd - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

and subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('nircmd.exe win close class "CabinetWClass"' , shell=True)
```

Comment: it works-thanks Sergev. but if i want to uninstall nircmd-how do i do it?

Comment: In FAQ (http://www.nirsoft.net/faq.html) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Q: I used the utilities of NirSoft, and I don't want them anymore. How do I uninstall them ?
------------------------ A: First, some utilities provide an installer with full uninstall support. If you downloaded a utility with installer, you should go to 'Add/Remove' software of Windows and unistall it. If you downloaded a utility in a ZIP file, you should simply delete the zip file, and the other files that you extracted from it.